# JSoup POST-запрос - проблемы при авторизации

Tags: java, android, post, cookie, jsoup

Задача - написать клиент на android для работы с данным разделом сайта  http://91.200.160.20/search.php. Однако никак не получается авторизоваться на нем. Используется библиотека jsoup.
Итак, для формирования post-запроса имеем:

```html
<form action="alogon.php" id="loginform" method="POST">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="158">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <label for="loginEnterToSite" class="labelLogin">№ читательского билета</label>
                <input name="id" value="" id="loginEnterToSite" type="text" style="width:143px;height:15px;">
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <label for="passwordEnterToSite" class="labelPass">ПИН - код</label>
                <input name="user_pass" id="passwordEnterToSite" value="" type="password" style="width:63px;height:15px">
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="41">
        <input type="image" name="submit" src="menu/loginimage/sup5.gif" style="border-style:none">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2>
        <input type=checkbox name=remember>Запомнить &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class='all_1' href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="Tip('<font color=#FF0000><b>Паролем является PIN код.</b></font><br><br>При утрате PIN кода необходимо обратиться в отдел &laquo;Учета и регистрации&raquo;.<br><br>Если у Вас нет PIN кода, то в качестве пароля можно использовать<br>первые буквы фамилии имени и отчества.<br><br>Например, читатель Iванов Євген Іванович,<br>читательский № 1234567 вводит номер Ч.Б. -<b><font color=#FF0000>1234567</font></b>, пароль - <b><font color=#FF0000>ІЄІ</font></b>', SHADOW, true, SHADOWWIDTH, 4, SHADOWCOLOR, '#007FFF')"
        onmouseout="UnTip()">Напомнить&nbsp;пароль</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

При регистрации с помощью браузера вот, что в заголовках происходит:

```
>**General**  
>Request URL:ttp://91.200.160.20/alogon.php  
>Request Method:POST  
>Status Code:302 Found  
>Remote Address:91.200.160.20:80  
>**Response Headers**  
>Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  
>Connection:Keep-Alive  
>Content-Encoding:gzip  
>Content-Length:20  
>Content-Type:text/html  
>Date:Thu, 09 Jun 2016 22:46:02 GMT  
>Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  
>Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100  
>Location:userpage.php  
>Pragma:no-cache  
>Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)  
>Set-Cookie:login=43750; expires=Sat, 09-Jul-2016 22:46:03 GMT  
>Set-Cookie:pass=73a39915788ab7f0e842fa37f8536c72; expires=Sat, 09-Jul-2016 22:46:03 GMT  
>Set-Cookie:pc_id=1805; expires=Fri, 09-Jun-2017 22:46:03 GMT  
>Vary:Accept-Encoding  
>X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u7  
>**Request Headers**  
>Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8  
>Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate  
>Accept-Language:uk,ru;q=0.8,en;q=0.6  
>Cache-Control:max-age=0  
>Connection:keep-alive  
>Content-Length:63  
>Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded  
>Cookie:PHPSESSID=2m26kdulqifq2tjt77fiihc8g5; pc_id=1805  
>Host:91.200.160.20  
>Origin:ttp://91.200.160.20  
>Referer:ttp://91.200.160.20/search.php  
>Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1  
>User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 YaBrowser/16.4.1.8949 Safari/537.36  
>**Form**  
>id:-----  
>user_pass:------  
>submit.x:20  
>submit.y:9  
>remember:on
```

В полях со ссылками "http" изменено на "ttp" в виду отсутствия репутации.

Код, который используется для авторизации и получения cookies:

```
Connection.Response loginGet = Jsoup.connect("http://91.200.160.20/search.php")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            Connection.Response loginPost = Jsoup.connect("http://91.200.160.20/alogon.php")
                    .data("id",mLog)
                    .data("user_pass",mPassword)
                    .data("submit.x", "27")
                    .data("submit.y", "13")
                    .data("remember", "on")
                    .cookies(loginGet.cookies())
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 YaBrowser/16.4.1.8949 Safari/537.36")
                    .referrer("http://91.200.160.20/search.php")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();

            Log.d("ex","loginPost" + loginPost.cookies());
            Log.d("ex","loginGet" + loginGet.cookies());
```

При выводе куков в логи вот, что получаю:

```
 D/ex: loginPost{login=deleted, pass=deleted}
 D/ex: loginGet{PHPSESSID=t21o83o1336qk5ea4mhf2var27, pc_id=2185}
```

Не могу понять, из-за чего пишет login=deleted и pass=deleted. Может ли это быть из-за того, что паролем является комбинация символов на кириллице? Если да, то не подскажете ли, как это можно обойти? А если нет, то из-за чего такая проблема может возникнуть и что я делаю не так?

Comment: Хорошо что приложили пароль. Так бы не смог найти ответ. Но лучше не выставлять личные данные. Теперь можете скрыть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наверное уже никому не нужно, но вдруг. Вот проверенное решение:

```java
Connection.Response loginPost = Jsoup.connect("http://91.200.160.20/alogon.php")
                .data("id", login)
                .data("user_pass", password)
                .cookies(loginGet.cookies())
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 YaBrowser/16.4.1.8949 Safari/537.36")
                .referrer("http://91.200.160.20/search.php")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .postDataCharset("windows-1251")
                .execute();
```

Именно **`.postDataCharset("windows-1251")`** исправляет ошибку.

В чём дело: Для отправки данных в POST запросе, их нужно предварительно закодировать в URL вид (так называемый [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)). При этом ваш русский пароль превращается в `%C1%C0%D0`. (Вы можете увидеть это в теле запроса вашего браузера при авторизации)

Когда вы делаете GET запрос на `/search`, значение `Content-Type` хидера является `text/html; charset=windows-1251`, что намекает браузеру продолжать общение с сервером в кодировке `win1251`, которую он и использует чтобы закодировать ваш пароль в URL виде.

Однако Jsoup этого не знает и использует стандартную `utf-8`. А в utf-8 русский кодируется по другому. Таким образом, явно указав кодировку, пароль кодируется правильно и сервер одобряет авторизацию.